# issue in loading redux framework options into wordpress widget activate & deactivate

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, redux-framework

I am trying to use reudx frame as option panel for a plugin. On this plugin, there is a widget which will be activated based on the settings of option panel.

For example, if the option panel, particular switch id is set to on /true /yes, then the widget should show on the widget manager section. Otherwise widget will not show in the widget manager section.

I have used following code, to get values to widget class file.

```
if ($GLOBALS['redux_demo']['myoption'] = true ) {
    add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_mywidget' );

}
```

**$redux_demo** is global setting for redux_options.
myoption is the id of the section, where the setting stores data

when i do print_r i get the value on $GLOBALS['redux_demo']['myoption'] as 1

but, when it put the code as above, the widget won't disapper, when the setting is marked to '0'.

please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try use:

```
if ($GLOBALS['redux_demo']['myoption']) {
    add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_mywidget' );

}
```